# How to handle an button click even from a .dll

Tags: vb.net, forms, dll, autodesk-inventor

Could someone please guide me as to how I would get this actually working? Currently it gives me errors about WithEvents - although simplified it shows the form - but I have no clue what that actually means. It's an toolbox I'm making just to allow the user to better interact with some of my other code.

All I need is the form visuals/guts to be custom, but then the code to be done within my application (which doesn't have visual editing capabilities).

Is this a case where I need to use interfacing/partial classes/inheritance, or can this easily be accomplished with just some minor tweaking to what I have?

(Form created in visual studio form designer and then changed to a class library. Application code written in Autodesk Inventor "rule" environment)

Thanks!

Application code:

```
AddReference "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\Release\SectionSymToolBox.dll" 

Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class SectionSymRule
'Public dlg As New System.Windows.Forms.For
Public Shared ToolBox As New SectionSymToolBox.SectionSymToolBox

Dim WithEvents EClass As New EventClass

Sub Main()
    ToolBox.Show()
End Sub

End Class
```

---

Form code:

```
Public Class SectionSymToolBox

Private Sub Main()
End Sub

Public Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'Swap Symbols
End Sub

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Flip Symbol
End Sub

Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Flip Text
End Sub

Public Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    '<
End Sub

Public Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
'>
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: *urrently it gives me errors about WithEvents* - which errors?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if I try using Handles _____ in my application code like :

Sub Navigage_Left(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolBox.Button4.Click

It gives errors; says like the handles requires a with events. 

My background is very limited in OOP, so I'm not even sure this is the right start to accessing the events.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error message there.  In order to use `Handles`, your variable (Button in this case) must be declared with the `WithEvents` keyword.  If you cannot change how the button is declared, then you can use the  `AddHandler` statement to wire up the events.

Comment: Do I need to do anything with the Handles attached to the form code?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
AddHandler ToolBox.Button1.Click, AddressOf HandlerMethodHere
```

Where HandlerMethod is a method that has the **same signature** as Button1.Click so for example:

```
Private Sub HandleButton1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
'Code here
End Sub
```

Obviously, replace Button1 with the name of the button.

Comment: Thanks! I feel like that's closer; except now it says:

Rule Compile Errors in Rule2, in FOR QUOTE idw.idw

Error on Line 9 : 'SectionSymToolBox.SectionSymToolBox.Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.

Where is it pulling friend from? I have that nowhere in my code. Unless I'm missing something more.

Comment: I solved this; I had to click into Form1.Vb in the Solution Explorer of Visual studio and change the lines 

Friend WithEvents Button3 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
To Public, and with your AddHandler Line it works perfect.

It's not closing/dispose the form properly though, so I think I have more work to do there...